# How to set error message if the content not found by search request

Tags: android

For Android apps, if the content is not in the search request, then how to show message "Sorry, we could not find your request"?

Answer (score -1):

Use this, when you need:

```
 Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry, we could not find your request" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```